# Load plugins in vim started with --noplugin

Tags: plugin-system, startup, invocation

I have my `$EDITOR` set to `vim --noplugin -n -i NONE +star`, which is what I usually want when committing with git etc.

However, sometimes I decide I need those plugins (the builtin `~/.vim/pack` kind, most of them `/opt/`-ional) after all. I can't seem to be able to load them; I've played with `set lpl`, `packloadall` and `so ~/.vimrc` but still plugins are unavailable.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

To load regular `plugin` files:

```
runtime! plugin/**/*.vim
```

(from `:help startup`, under `:help load-plugins`)

---

For packages, the story is a bit more complex. What I can suss out:

- `:packloadall` loads non-optional (i.e., `start`) packages; use the `!` to force it ("Packages will be loaded only once. […] When the optional ! is added this command will load packages even when done before.")

  - this command adds directories to the `runtimepath`, then sources the `plugin` files from only those directories (kind of like the above, but not)
- `:packadd` adds the named `opt` package to `runtimepath` (but if loading from `start` was skipped, it tries there first). Then it sources the `plugin` files. With `!`, the only step is to add directories.

Comment: My .vimrc calls several :packadd's, but apparently, even after `set lpl`, they are still ignored when I re-source vimrc